# Acessar SQL Server Express remotamente no Google Cloud Platform

Tags: sql-server, servidor

Eu estou com um servidor no GCP e está tudo funcionando corretamente(IIS, SQL Server...).
Mas eu gostaria de acessar remotamente um banco de dados que está nesse servidor.

Eu já fiz esse procedimento:
http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837

Já criei a regra no firewall do GCP também (Conforme a imagem).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mas ainda sim não consigo acessar o banco

Comment: Estava faltando liberar o Firewall do windows. Fiz a configuração e funcionou corretamente. Valeu!

Comment: Thiago..
Obrigado, estava faltando liberar a porta no firewall do Windows.